# R print out matrix with row and column names using apply

Tags: r, apply

I have the following matrix 'x'

```
   a b
a 1 3
b 2 4
```

It is a really large matrix (trimmed down for this question)
I would like to print out this matrix by each row name and column name combination along with the value in that cell. So the expected output would be

```
a,a,1
a,b,3
b,a,2
b,b,4
```

I could loop through them, but I'm pretty sure this can be avoided (apply?). Any pointers much appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way is to use the `melt` function from the `reshape2` package.

```
x <- matrix(1:4, nrow = 2, ncol = 2,
            dimnames = list(dim1 = c("a", "b"), dim2 = c("a", "b")))

library(reshape2)
melt(x)
#   dim1 dim2 value
# 1    a    a     1
# 2    b    a     2
# 3    a    b     3
# 4    b    b     4
```

**Edit** 
If your data is so big that speed is an issue, I would also suggest:

```
data.frame(dim1 = rep(rownames(x), ncol(x)),
           dim2 = rep(colnames(x), each = nrow(x)),
           value = c(x))
```

**Edit2**

After testing with relatively big data, I would not rule out `melt`:

```
x <- matrix(runif(9e6), nrow = 3000, ncol = 3000,
            dimnames = list(dim1 = paste0("x", runif(3000)),
                            dim2 = paste0("y", runif(3000))))

system.time(y1 <- melt(x))
# user  system elapsed 
# 1.17    0.44    1.61 

system.time(y2 <- data.frame(dim1 = rep(rownames(x), ncol(x)),
                             dim2 = rep(colnames(x), each = nrow(x)),
                             value = c(x)))
# user  system elapsed 
# 1.98    0.37    2.36
```

Comment: Melt sounds like a good suggestion. But the volume of data is quite large and I think it would slow down significantly.

Comment: How big exactly? You might want to add that to your question.

Comment: That is most helpful. Mine worked with melt too. Much easier to use.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the base R function `row` and  `col`

If you want to reference the `row.names` and `col.names` then use `as.factor = T`. Using `as.character` and `as.numeric` flattens the matrix.

```
do.call(data.frame,list(lapply(list(row = row(x, T),col=col(x,T)), as.character), 
                         value =as.numeric(x)))

##  row col value
## 1   a   a     1
## 2   b   a     2
## 3   a   b     3
## 4   b   b     4
```

If you want a `matrix` you will need to have all the columns as the same class (`character` or `numeric`. You could then use

```
do.call(cbind, lapply(list(row = row(x), col = col(x), value = x), as.numeric))

##      row col value
## [1,]   1   1     1
## [2,]   2   1     2
## [3,]   1   2     3
## [4,]   2   2     4
```

Or as character

```
do.call(cbind, lapply(list(row = row(x, T), col = col(x, T), value = x), as.character))
##     row col value
## [1,] "a" "a" "1"  
## [2,] "b" "a" "2"  
## [3,] "a" "b" "3"  
## [4,] "b" "b" "4"
```